# RabbitMQ version exposed in STOMP header

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp

I use rabbitmq with the stomp plugin and in the stomp header of the **CONNECTED** message this **'server': 'RabbitMQ/3.6.5'** appears.
Is the there a configuration options to avoid that this information is exposed in the header ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is exist option: `rabbitmq_stomp.hide_server_info`

More information here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stomp/pull/81